# C: Correct way to print "unsigned long" in hex

Tags: c, printf

I have a function that gets an **unsigned long** variable as parameter and I want to print it in Hex.

What is the correct way to do it?

Currently, I use **printf** with **"%lx"**

```
void printAddress(unsigned long address) {
    printf("%lx\n", address);
}
```

Should I look for a printf pattern for **unsigned** long hex? (and not just "long hex" as mentioned above)

Or does **printf** convert numbers to hex only using the bits? - so I should not care about the sign anyway?

### Edit/Clarification

This question was rooted in a **confusion**: hex is just another way to express **bits**, which means that signed/unsigned number is just an interpretation. The fact that the type is **unsigned** long therefore doesn't change the hex digits. Unsigned just tells you how to interpret those same bits in your computer program.

Comment: What problem are you facing with `%lx` ? This should be fine for an unsigned long. Of course if your `address` parameter really is an address then you should probably be passing it as `void *` and printing it with `%p`.

Comment: This `address` is not a real pointer in a C program - it is an address of a simulated machine, not always in the same size as a pointer on my machine.

Comment: What `printf` lacks is a way to print _signed hexadecimal numbers_...

Comment: I did not get a problem yet, but I'm afraid that with too high values, it will see it as "long" and not as "unsigned long"

Comment: @KerrekSB, my question was probably not written very well. My actual question was whether I can use "%lx" even though the type is unsigned. I don't think it is so trivial

Comment: Actually I now see that in cplusplus.com it is written very boldly that "x" is unsigned hex. You were right, my question is not very useful...

Comment: sign should not matter, since Hex is just another way to represent bits. It is up to you to decide whether to interpret the bits as a signed or an unsigned number

Comment: It's funny to see that people still ask themselves this question and reach this thread. Hex is just a higher-level representation of bits, which are of course not related to the sign. The signed/unsigned is just an interpretation  :)

Comment: "sign should not matter, since Hex is just another way to represent bits." is incorrect.  `"%lx"` matches `unsigned long` which is never negative.  C lacks a specify to print `long` with a negative value in "hex".  To print `-100L` in hex requires other code to print correctly in hexadecimal.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I was trying to say that interpreting the bits as signed/unsigned is up to you. Some combinations of bits can be interpreted as very large positive numbers, or as negative numbers, depending on whether you use signed/unsigned type to interpret them. The bits themselves have no sign, and hex is just another way to represent bits, so it shouldn't have a sign either. By using `"%lx"` you simply tell `printf` to print 64 bits in hex. Am I wrong?

Comment: @SomethingSomething Passing a negative `long` and printing via  `"%lx:` is undefined behavior.  The code need not print based on a sign agnostic bit pattern, nor not print at all, it is UB.  With `"%lx"`, pass an `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You're doing it right.

From [the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> o, u, x, X
>
> The unsigned int argument is converted to unsigned octal (o), unsigned decimal (u), or unsigned hexadecimal (x and X) notation.

So the value for `x` should always be `unsigned`. To make it `long` in size, use:

> l
>
> (ell) A following integer conversion corresponds to a long int or unsigned long int argument [...]

So `%lx` is `unsigned long`. An address (pointer value), however, should be printed with `%p` and cast to `void *`.

Comment: So actually the conclusion is that "%lx" is anyway unsigned.. Thanks!

Comment: "So %lx is unsigned long" sounds like the format specifier is `unsigned long`.  Better stated as `"%lx"` should by used _with_ `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 10):

I think the following format specifier should work
give it a try

`printf("%#lx\n",address);`

Comment: Close, but no cigar!  Either use `printf("0x%lx\n",address);` or `printf("%#lx\n",address);` but not both.  The first will print the value `0UL` as `0x0` while the second will just output `0`.  This suggestion will teach the OP something but is unrelated to the question.